# GmailApp.getUserLabelByName() no longer returns GmailLabel

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a few scripts that scan my inbox for certain emails and automatically process their contents. These stopped working a while back.

I just tried rewriting one of them and noticed that no matter what label I try and get, `GmailApp.getUserLabelByName()` always returns `null`.

Example:

```
function getLabel(){
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Script Unprocessed");
  Logger.log(label);
}
```

This returns null even though I have a `Script Unprocessed` label, with emails, and returns `null` for any label I've tried.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Works for my labels.  Is your script authorized to access GmailApp?

Comment: @Desire It is, I created a new script just to be sure and authed it.

Answer (score 0):

The getUserLabelByName() method would only retrieve user-created labels while Inbox is a system label in Gmail. The code seems to work for user labels.

```
function getLabelName(name) {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(name);
  Logger.log(label.getName());
}
```

Comment: Amit, I am using this on user-created labels , I used that as an example, turns out this was a poor example. I am changing it now.

Answer (score 0):

It is also working with my gmail/labels. Another way to get the threads/messages for that label is with [search()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String)):

```
function getLabel () {
  var label = GmailApp.search('label:Script Unprocessed');
  // returns the message count in the first thread within `Script Unprocessed`
  Logger.log(label[0].getMessageCount()); 
}
```